# C++ паттерн "стратегия"

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Попробовал, перепеписать код из книжки Head First про паттерны, на C++, но появляется ошибка E0322 object of abstract class type "MallardDuck" is not allowed: Duck d:\Code\CODE\C++\Duck\Duck\Source.cpp 119 т.е. компилятор не видит реализованный класс.
    #include "iostream"
    using namespace std;

```
class IFlyBehavior
{
public:
    virtual void fly() = 0;
};

class FlyWithWings : public IFlyBehavior
{
public:
    void fly() override
    {
        cout << "fly!";
    }
};
class FlyNoWay : public IFlyBehavior
{
public:
    void fly() override
    {
        cout << "no fly!";
    }
};

class IQuackBehavior
{
public:
    virtual void quack() = 0;
};
class Quack : public IQuackBehavior
{
public:
    void quack() override
    {
        cout << "Quack!";
    }
};
class Squeak : public IQuackBehavior
{
public:
    void quack() override
    {
        cout << "Squeak!";
    }
};
class MuteQuack : public IQuackBehavior
{
public:
    void quack() override
    {
        cout << "Can't quack";
    }
};

class Duck : public IFlyBehavior, IQuackBehavior
{
public:
    FlyWithWings* fly_behavior;
    Quack* quack_behavior;
    void swim()
    {
        cout << "Swim!";
    }
    virtual void display() = 0;
    void performQuack()
    {
        quack_behavior->quack();
    }
    void performFly()
    {
        fly_behavior->fly();
    }
};

class MallardDuck : public Duck
{
public:
    MallardDuck()
    {
        quack_behavior = new Quack();
        fly_behavior = new FlyWithWings();
    }

    void display() override
    {
        cout << "Mallard!";
    }
};
class RedheadDuck : public Duck
{
public:
    void display() override
    {
        cout << "RedHead!";
    }
};
class DecoyDuck : public Duck
{
public:
    void display() override
    {
        cout << "DecoyDuck!";
    }
};
class RubberDuck : Duck
{
public:
    void display() override
    {
        cout << "RubberDuck!";
    }
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Duck* md = new MallardDuck;
    md->performFly();
    md->performFly();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: сдаётся мне, Утка не должна являеться ни "Манерой полёта", ни "Манерой кряканья".... ЗЫ: книжка точно плюсовая, а не про какой-то сорт кофе? в последнем случае рекомендую начать с классики («Design patterns») вместо неё... или хотя бы иметь её под рукой...

Comment: В книге примеры на java

Answer (score 3):

В `MallardDuck` не реализованы функции `fly` и `quack`. Они остались чисто виртуальными от базовых классов. Нужно эти реализации обеспечить.

На самом деле, просто вместо `perform-`функций надо использовать имена из интерфейсных классов и тогда всё будет ок:

```
void quack() override
{
    quack_behavior->quack();
}
void fly() override
{
    fly_behavior->fly();
}
```

Ну и в `main` поправить само собой. [Тест](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KhUjYFlRWb6mzHiV)

Comment: Базовый класс реализует интерфейс IFlyBehavior, IQuackBehavior которые реализуют классы с нужными методами.

Comment: @BlackDimkoss у Вас базовые классы не те, которые должны быть, судя по всему.